# why can't I connect to mysql database in eclipse?

Tags: mysql, eclipse

I'm unable to detect a MySQL connection when I'm in Eclipse. I currently run MySQL in a docker container and created a database `y9` and a username of `yannik`.
[image]

[image]

I just want to know if there's anything I'm doing wrong here because I'm failing to connect to my local MySQL instance.

Stack-trace I get is

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you show with text the `stacktrace`? not use image like that..

Comment: [This answer could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: don't understand most of these solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: You can see `balus` statement.. Basically the eclipse didn't get respond from your db..

Comment: I know that but I don't know how to do that when my MySQL is a docker container.

Comment: If you're running it in a container, tell us which ports you're opening in the `docker run` invocation.

Comment: Using port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Make your JDBC CONNECTION URLin eclipse follow this pattern.

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql_container:3306/db_nameserverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"&verifyServerCertificate=FALSE
```